# How to limit several spinners in JavaFX by a shared pool of points

Tags: java, javafx

A spinner allows you to add a lower and upper limit. The thing I want to do is have several spinners and additionally have a pool of points that you can spend. I want them to decrease every time you increase the value on any of the spinners and increase if you do the opposite. And of course I want you to not be able to increase any of the spinners even more if you're out of points.

Think of it as spending money and choosing which products to add to your cart. With every amount of products you increase you spend one money and once you spend it all, you can't do it anymore.

I know how to set up each spinner. How to give them an internal limit and default value. I can also set up a simple int for the amount of points you get.

Answer (score 0):

The basic plan for this is to create an observable property which holds the number of "points" that are left. Each spinner's value factory can observe this property and update the maximum value accordingly. And then, conversely, adjust the property when the value of each spinner changes.

Here's one way of doing this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class App extends Application {
    
    private final int maxCredits = 100 ;
    private final int numSpinners = 5 ;
    private final IntegerProperty creditsRemaining = new SimpleIntegerProperty(maxCredits);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        Label creditsRemainingLabel = new Label();
        creditsRemainingLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Credits remaining: %d", creditsRemaining));
        root.getChildren().add(creditsRemainingLabel);
        
        for (int i = 0; i<numSpinners ; i++) {
            IntegerSpinnerValueFactory factory = new IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, maxCredits, 0);
            factory.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                    () -> creditsRemaining.get() + factory.getValue(),
                    creditsRemaining, factory.valueProperty()
            ));
            
            factory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
                creditsRemaining.set(creditsRemaining.get() - newValue.intValue() + oldValue.intValue()));
            
            root.getChildren().add(new Spinner<>(factory));
        }
        

        
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Javik Just adapt it to do that. You obviously need to start by specifying what behavior you want as the total represented by all the spinners increases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Since I want the upper limit to be still set originally independent of the amount of left money (you can only buy let's say 20 of any product) then I don't even need to add the listener to the maxProperty if I understand correctly and only need the second part?

Comment: I tried applying that and it gets weird, I'm able to distribute points despite having a negative amount of points left.